# Looking for a way to output 100-144 Analog Channels from Arduino

Tags: arduino, multiplexer, dac, shift-register, 74hc595

I've been searching for days and found 2 ways that could work, but not sure about implementation:

1. Using shift registers like in: http://tronixstuff.com/2011/08/26/tutorial-maximising-your-arduinos-io-ports/
2. 74HC595 Multiplexing with lots of ICs 20+ IC not that attractive of an idea

**Questions:**

1 How to implement some basic DAC with one setting controlling all channels' output levels simultaneously.

2. I need 5-20 volts out, 0.5-1 micro-second resolution (for square wave pulses)
3. Pulse Width is (PW in image) can range from 10-100 uS and Pulse Period is (PP in image) can range from 10-100 uS. This needs to be achievable in Arduino software (or similar microcontroller - open to the Raspberry Pi if needed). Is this resolution within Arduino's clock ability? Do I need to move to a faster microcontroller?
4. I could divide the grid say in 36x36 blocks (4 of them) and have them scan - raster simultaneously, therefore asking less performance from the arduino...

The image should indicate the type of pulse I need to output.

*The final result needed is to produce geometrical patterns, moving around a matrix of analog output devices. The pulse info is 'the experiment'. This is from an old lost project I'm trying to figure out how to recreate.

^I'd like the pulse parameters to be precise and consistent

^I'd probably prefer using shift registers

Like a primitive TV of sorts.

Thanks for help !

[image]

Comment: Where did you get the image from? Was there no component number with it? Have you also considered using more than one switch / mux? Like multiple 4:1 multiplexers?

Comment: Question Edited as requested.

Comment: You've obviously redacted a lot of important information out of the diagram, such as the amount of time between groups of pulses, and the degree to which you need to generate multiple pulses on different outputs at the same time.

Comment: Added more info on the image and in the text - hope it is clear now. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: You say "Analog" in your question title yet the question is talking about PWM. Which one is it? PWM output may approximate analog in some situations but it isn't the same. If you want true analog you'll need to add filtering components (or use off the shelf DACs). With that kind of timing required for that many outputs, you might want to consider an FPGA.

Comment: It would really help if you could say what the end application is. Now you hint something along the lines of "like an old TV of sorts". Does your end application have something to do with displaying an image of some kind?

Comment: End device is analog, like a light bulb. But it may be a digital signal with an amp to 20 volts - adjustable with a variable resistor. Origianl drawings from the 80's seem to use a analog demux, which I don't seem to find at all.

Comment: It is for use on skin, on wounds or elsewhere for pain reduction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The title of the question says you need lots of analog channels. It looks like you mean digital channels with variable voltages (since each channel is only on or off). 100 channels is *a lot*, no matter what you do, you're going to have a lot of ICs. The shift registers are probably your best bet, they are simple and data can be shifted into them very fast.

Let's say you need 10 us update time. With 100 bits of display data that is 10 MHz. The SPI on an Arduino can not shift out that fast. The Uno has a 16 Mhz clock and the fastest you can set SPI is 1/2 the clock speed. This is to say nothing about actually getting the data lined up. So you will need something faster and more powerful.

For the variable output voltage, the simplest would probably be a DAC with an op-amp to scale it up to ~20V and a current buffer.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense. Maybe a Rasberry PI or BananaPI. I have no clue how it was done before... I know they used four 6x6 instead and raster scanned them simultaneously, but of the top of my head, not sure why that would be an advantage speed-wise...

Comment: You would then have four channels each doing only 2.5 MHz, so it may be easier. The CPU would still have to do just as much work feeding the data in though. Also note that the Arduino only has one SPI port, so you would have to shift the bits out manually, which is a lot more overhead.

Comment: Hi, so a shift register with a RasberryPI ? Would that be a good path to pursue? Thanks !

Comment: Yes, you should be able to go pretty far with that. I haven't used the RaspberryPI much, so I don't know what the software side will look like.

Are the individual pulses really necessary for the output devices? Could you use a 100 us pulse instead of 10 10 us ones? That would reduce your speed requirements and simplify the processing.

Comment: I forgot to mention the the shift registers can all be daisy-chained. You connect the data shifting out of the first one into the shift-in pin for the second one, and so on. This way you only need one SPI port.

Comment: "Are the individual pulses really necessary for the output devices?"

Answer: Yes, they affect the feeling on the skin as well as numbness.